# Question on javascript and jscript

Tags: javascript

Does Javascript and jscript are implemenations of EMCA script.?Why standards are named as EMCA script. what is EMCA script?

Comment: Perhaps you're having trouble finding it as the correct spelling is [ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript)

Answer (score 1):

Both JScript and JavaScript are implementation of ECMAScript.

JavaScript came first, and was developed as part of Netscape browser.

JScript is Microsoft own implementation of ECMAScript, with the same basic things but also with some changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an good article on history of JavaScript, Jscript and Ecma: http://oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/2001/04/06/js_history.html

Answer (score 0):

For information about javascript: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript

> JavaScript is an implementation of the ECMAScript language standard and is primarily used in the form of client-side JavaScript

Comment: You still didn't answer the main question here - he did not ask what is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[This is ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

There's a little info on Wikipedia about it too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript